# How to open apps on TWM window manager without using xterm

Tags: command-line, window-manager, twm

My machine boots into command-line and then I run the following command to open a display with TWM window manager on it:

```
$ xinit /usr/local/bin/twm
```

On TWM, this is how I run apps: I left-click anywhere on the black screen and a menu shows up. Then I select `xterm` and on `xterm` command-line, I run my app for example:

```
$ opera
```

The problem is that for every app, I need a `xterm` to be opened first. I wonder if there is any other way by which I can open my apps without having to open `xterm`. Thanks.

---

I ended up compiling/installing version 2.6.7 of [fvwm](https://github.com/fvwmorg/fvwm) which is also suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131128/155643). It is a cool window manager with many [features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FVWM#Features).

Comment: twm's [manual page](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/twm.1.html) explains menus, and it comes with samples...

Comment: @ThomasDickey Right, I think I can add options to menus with statements like this: `"Opera"         f.exec "exec opera &"`

Comment: Twm is one of the oldest window managers. Fvwm was one of the most powerful window managers in the 1990s. Today fvwm is still a contender but [there are many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_X_window_managers) [many](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/window_manager) [many](http://www.xwinman.org/others.php) [more](https://www.gilesorr.com/wm/table.html).

Comment: @Gilles It's a whole lot of window managers, I'm curious which one would you recommend on such a [machine](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/latit/en/spec_latit_d820_en.pdf) from 2005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a menu in your `.twmrc`, like:

```
Menu "MyMenu"
{
    "Opera" f.exec "Opera"
}
```

Then bind it to your left mouse button instead of the default one:

```
Button1 = : root : f.menu "MyMenu"
```

Look at [TWM(1)](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/twm.1.html) to see how to configure TWM according to you needs. You may also want to see examples of configuration at [xwinman.org](http://www.xwinman.org/vtwm.php).

TWM lacks the feature of generating dynamic menus, so you'll need to define a menu for every set of apps you want to be accessible that way, or you can use the [xdgmenumaker](https://github.com/gapan/xdgmenumaker) utility.

Comment: I ended up compiling/installing version 2.6.7 of [fvwm](https://github.com/fvwmorg/fvwm) which is cool. It supports full-screen feature, and many more.